# How to set 2 rows height in percent using jquery mobile?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I want to define 2 rows in one page using jquery mobile, and I want to do it in percentage.

```
<div data-role="content">
   <div id="divParteSuperior" style="height:300px;">
   </div>
   <div id="divParteInferior">
   </div>
</div>
```

When I do using height it works, but I need to use percent, if I set height equal to 60%, it doesn't work. I have search if this could be done using jquery mobile grid, but it only talks about columns. I want to use all the entire height of the page.

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image: What i want to do like]

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#divParteSuperior, #divParteInferior").height($(window).height()/2 + "px")
```

**That's the jQ answer.** And you might want to put that in $(window).resize();

**The CSS answer would be:**

1) Make the content inherit 100% height from the `<body>` and the `<html>` so that you can make the divs with % height

2) Use vh instead of % (not that well supported on mobile without a polyfill)

3) Use display table or flexbox

Comment: Hi, thank for reply. Is there no way to do this by css?

Answer (score 0):

See this article for making the content take the device height:
https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/02/06/content-div-height-fill-page-height/

Once content height is set you can then use percentage height on the row DIVS. Note that by default the content div in jQM has padding.

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
       <div id="divParteSuperior" >
       row 1
       </div>
       <div id="divParteInferior">
       row 2
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

function contentHeight() {
    var screen = $.mobile.getScreenHeight(),
        contentCurrent = $(".ui-content").outerHeight() - $(".ui-content").height(),
        content = screen - contentCurrent;
    /* apply result */
    $(".ui-content").height(content);
}

$(document).on("pagecontainertransition", contentHeight);
$(window).on("throttledresize orientationchange", contentHeight);

.ui-content {
  background: blue;
  padding: 0;
}
#divParteSuperior {
  background: green;
  height: 60%;
}
#divParteInferior {
  background: red;
  height: 40%;
}
```

## **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/qge77uL9/)**